# Symfony2 multilingual website data distribution

Tags: symfony-2.1

I have created a website in Symfony2 using website.com/_locale/xxxxxxxx routing to translate static data into two languages. This implementation works successfully but I wish to go further than that. I want to run this website for several other countries and a proper transformation is necessary in order to have those countries (with different languages) managed into one website.

Let's say I have an entity for Shops. Each object created has some variables like Address, kind of business, equipment etc. This allows the user to create an entry in his own language but all entries will be mixed in the table. The table will have italian, english, spanish data and when someone enters the website from a different location, we unfortunately have to view the other language's data.

I want the user to have the ability to create a new Shop in two languages: English and his own. The solutions I have thought of are:

- I will create a new column in the same table for example "original_language" and every entry will be stored with a locale: en_US, es_SP etc. When the website wants to retrieve a row will search through ONE table will thousands of entries.
- I will create another table which will be the mirror of the original one, in another language. This means that I will have a Shops table/entity, a Shops_it, a Shops_es, a Shops_br etc. Unfortunately this solution will need me to create several tables and relationships between other linked tables.
- I will create another column in the same row for each field. The Shops.description, Shops.address etc. will also include Shops.description_en, Shops.description_br, Shops.address_en, Shops.address_br etc.

What is the safest, quickest and more professional way to do what I want?

Comment: Don't go with multiple tables/columns! That's horrific and I got to deal with it on legacy databases! Just don't!

Comment: So is this a bad practice ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Anything you'd represent as a collection/indexed collection is a table in SQL. If you got multiple values for a field, that's an 1-n relation.

Comment: So do you have a suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the `[DoctrineExtensions][1]` lib to get your columns translated (it uses an EAV-alike structure for translations) or write `1-n` relations for translated entities, having a "base" entity and a "translated" one. You can use the [`indexBy`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetomany) attribute of collections to make fetching and logic easier to handle.

Comment: Ok, I understood what you suggested but I believe you misunderstood a little. There has nothing to do with translation, but keeping data for the same entity in different languages. The Shop might have the same name in both languages but the data may be altered. The user might need to set different data for the English and the Spanish description. But the entity structure is absolutely the same.

Comment: It's still a translation-related concept

Comment: it's a database related concept. The problem is how the data are going to be saved and retrieved from the database.

Comment: Someone told me about JSON data inside a row with a unique id but I am not sure If it's a safe solution though.

Comment: Well, you basically have your 1-n collection and index it by language ;)

Regardless if it is a number, a string or a blob.

Comment: Nope, serializing data into a field is not a good idea. You're working with a relational DB, not with a NoSQL AFAIK.

Comment: Ocramius I really apologise for haven't accepted your reply earlier. Even though I haven't tested the translatable extension I have read about this extension. I guess you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

as Ocramius suggested, use the [Doctrine translatable extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md)